# Error Cannot access zza

Tags: java, android

I am trying to run my app however getting an error when trying to run my app .

build.gradle:

```
dependencies {

implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
androidTestImplementation('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.3.1'
annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.3.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.+'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

//maps
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.0.1'

//personal firebase database
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:3.3.1'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:3.3.1'

implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'

} 
//apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

ERROR:

> error: cannot access zza class file for
>   com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.zza not found

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this also :

```
  api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

And if you are using proguard add this in the file :

```
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-dontwarn com.google.firebase.messaging.**
```

Hope this will help.